# How to delete excel worksheets in VBA?

Tags: vba

How to delete all excel sheets in a workbook except the first two sheets using for next Loop ?

```
For 
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider:

```
Sub Killer()
    j = Sheets.Count
    For i = j To 3 Step -1
        Sheets(i).Delete
    Next i
End Sub
```

If you like, you can disable Alerts before running the loop.

Comment: @SNipErHex  You are quite welcome!

Comment: I suggest wrapping the loop with `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` and `Application.DisplayAlerts = True` to avoid the [confirmation box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3lgP.png).